Using JAXB2 Basics Plugins for XJC in gradle tasks
Trying to create beans from XSD files with toString methid using JAXB2 basics plugin but receiving error "unknown parameter -XtoString"
Hello,
I would like to generate java classes with toString-methods with the JAXB2 plugin. My code is currently looking like this:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.unbroken-dome.xjc' version '2.0.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0.0'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)) // Set Java version
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Jakarta XML Bind API
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.2'

    // XJC for generating beans
    annotationProcessor 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:0.13.1'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:0.13.1'
}

def schemaDir = file("src/main/resources/xsd") // Directory for XSD files
def outputDir = file("$buildDir/generated-sources/xjc") // Directory for generated classes



// New version of legacy task (see below)
// Task to generate Java beans from XSDs
task generateBeans {
    group = "code generation"
    description = "Generates Java Beans from XSD schemas"

    doFirst {
        delete outputDir
        mkdir outputDir
        println("Before XJC task")
    }

    doLast {
        println("Start processing XSD files")
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc',
                classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask',
                classpath: configurations.annotationProcessor.asPath)

        fileTree(schemaDir).matching { include '**/*.xsd' }.files.each { xsdFile ->
            logger.lifecycle("Generating Java classes for schema: ${xsdFile}")
            println("Generating Java classes for schema: ${xsdFile}")
            println "Processing XSD: ${xsdFile}"

            def targetPackage = 'com.example.generated'
            ant.xjc(destdir: outputDir,
                    package: targetPackage,
                    extension: true) {
                schema(file: xsdFile)
                arg(value: '-XtoString') // Aktiviert das ToString-Plugin
            }
        }
        println("Finished processing XSD files")
    }
}

and an example XSD looks like this
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

I am receiving the error
Execution failed for task ':generateBeans'.
> unknown parameter -XtoString

I already consulted the documentation as found here but I couldn't find any intro on how to use the plugin with gradle.
EDIT: I wonder why arg(line: "-Xlocator") does work though.
We are migrating from a far older version of JAXB. Is it outdated?
Thanks and best wishes

Solution found. I hope this helps:
The jaxb2-basics plugin is also deprecated. The detailed migration can be found here.
The code now looks like this:
    plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0.0'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)) 
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    annotationProcessor
}

dependencies {
    // Jakarta XML Bind API
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.8' // Required for the generated Java classes' dependencies (e.g. strategies)


    // annotationProcessor configuration:

    // XJC for generating beans
    annotationProcessor 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.2'

    // JAXB2 plugins (formerly: JAXB2 basics plugin) (used for ant task below)
    annotationProcessor 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.8'
    // requires
    annotationProcessor 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins-runtime:4.0.8'
    //annotationProcessor 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins-tools:4.0.8'
    //requires:
    annotationProcessor 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.2'
    //Without jaxb-runtime, you'll get: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory
    //annotationProcessor 'con.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.4'
}

def schemaDir = file("src/main/resources/xsd") // Directory for XSD files
def outputDir = file("$buildDir/generated-sources/xjc") // Directory for generated classes

task generateBeans {
    group = "code generation"
    description = "Generates Java Beans from XSD schemas"

    doFirst {
        delete outputDir
        mkdir outputDir
        println("Before XJC task") // Debugging 
    }

    doLast {
        println("Start processing XSD files") // Debugging 
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc',
                classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask',
                classpath: configurations.annotationProcessor.asPath)

        fileTree(schemaDir).matching { include '**/*.xsd' }.files.each { xsdFile ->
            logger.lifecycle("Generating Java classes for schema: ${xsdFile}")
            println("Generating Java classes for schema: ${xsdFile}")
            println "Processing XSD: ${xsdFile}"

            def targetPackage = 'com.example.generated'
            ant.xjc(destdir: outputDir,
                    package: targetPackage,
                    extension: true) {
                schema(file: xsdFile)
                arg(line: "-XtoString")
                arg(line: "-Xequals")
                arg(line: "-XhashCode")
                arg(line: "-Xlocator")
                //arg(value: '-XtoString') // Never use an argument twice, the generated class will have redundant methods!
            }
        }
        println("Finished processing XSD files")
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
